# How does the shifting work when we use the unique function on a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

So, I am currently reading on some c++ stuff and I came across this example on cppreference and I couldn't understand how the shift works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1};
    std::vector<int>::iterator last;

    last = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()); // 1 2 3 2 1 3 2 2 1
                                            //           ^
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != last; ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

I understand that when we use unique it shifts things over, however I am **not sure** how we obtain the sequence given to us from `last` to `v.end()`.

Through my own drawings on paper I understand how we achieve the sequence from `v.begin()` to `v.last()`, but not the sequence from `v.last()` to `v.end()` as mentioned.

Here is the [reference site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking here. Once I change the construction of `v` so that it compiles, when I run, I get an expect output.

Comment: "...can someone explain to me how we get 3 2 2 1" Sure, *we don't* : [see it live](http://ideone.com/gLyemr). Do you mean the *leftover* elements (in your code, from `last` up to `v.end()` )?

Comment: Yes, I was wondering how they got the last up to v.end

Comment: Ok. that's important, and may be the thing people are going "huh?" about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std:unique` indeed just shifts elements toward the beginning as needed. The shift isn't like you may be thinking. It doesn't need to be some propagated one-element-at-a-time-thing. It can take advantage of the requirement the element must be *move-assignable*. Per the definition of move-assignment, once an element is moved, its prior content is unspecified. In your case, it just keeps the "value" there, but it isn't a *specified* value.

In short, what you're seeing is leftover values, and *some* of them may be *non-specific*.

The following is a simple demo using your data. Initially we have two slot locations, R, and a W. I make no warrants this is **the** algorithm used by `std::unique` (I honestly don't know).

Casing out the trivial case (0 or 1-length sequence), when a value is to be *kept* it is move-assigned in the *next* slot above the W, and W is advanced. Regardless of whether it is kept or not, the R is always advanced. When done, the slot *past* W is the `last` (i.e. the first of the left over slots, some of which can have unspecified values).

Given your data, the sequence would be something like this:

```
1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1 - different, since the write target
W  R                        is the same as the read-point, do nothing,
                            and advance both R and W

1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1 - equivalent, advance R only
   W  R                     

1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1 - equivalent, advance R only
   W     R                     

1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1 - different, move the 3 to the next write
   W        R               point and advance both R and W

1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1 - equivalent, advance R only
      W        R

1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1 - different, move the 2 to the next write
      W           R         slot and advance both R and W

1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1 - equivalent, advance R only
         W           R      

1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1 - different, move the 1 to the next write
         W              R   slot and advance both R and W

1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1 - read is at end-of-sequence
            W             R
```

At this point, the reader is finished. the first slot past W is `last` as the algorithm goes (and may indeed be `end` if the original sequence had no duplicates). I leave you the challenge of determining which elements (3,2,2,1) are in the "unspecified" state after this is done.

<sub>Hint: what was moved? What was skipped? What was overwritten? Why does it matter? Try writing `0` on the read slot of anything that is *moved* and see what is leftover in the sequence from `last` to `end`.</sub>

Comment: I like your visual illustration!

Comment: Sorry for late reply, this visual really helped me a lot!

Answer (score 4):

The unique algorithm is very simple. Given a range, [First,Last), you use two iterators, `In` and `Out` to remove consecutive duplicates. `In` and `Out` are initially assigned to the first element in the sequence.

```
In = Out = First
```

The algorithm then proceeds as follows, provided that the range is not empty.

```
while (++In != Last)
{
    if (*In != *Out)
    {
        ++Out;
        *Out = *In;
    }
}
```

Now simply continue until In has reached the end of the range. Then we return `++Out`.

`Out` is basically an output iterator writing the unique elements into the same range, so we can retrieve the last iterator by incrementing that after the algorithm above has finished.

It's easier if you don't think of it in terms of *shifting* but *outputting* to (and overwriting) the same range. The only tricky part is that we're overwriting the same range we're reading. It's a lot easier to grasp the algorithm if you are pushing back unique elements to a different sequence and returning that sequence. Now you just apply a small optimization to avoid requiring a separate output range by overwriting the same one you are reading.

Here's a quick implementation I whipped up which might be a little easier to understand than vendor versions. It's devoid of some of the usual fluff like reusing 'first' as the input iterator, uses operator!= (instead of ! and ==), etc.

```
template <class Iterator>
Iterator my_unique(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    if (first != last)
    {
        Iterator in = first;
        Iterator out = first;
        while (++in != last)
        {
            if (*in != *out)
            {
                ++out;
                *out = *in;
            }
        }
        return ++out;
    }
    return last;
}
```